# javascriptが動いていません

Tags: javascript

完全に初心者です。
今回本を購入し、早速サンプルコードを動かしてみたのですが、javascript部分が全く反映されていませんでした。
コードは下記になります。
考えられる原因について、ご教示頂けるとありがたいです。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMCintentLoaded",function(){
            var nowDate = new Date();
            var fullYear = nowDate.getFullYear();
            var shortYear = Striong(fullYear).substr(2,2);
            var heiseiYear = Number(shortYear) + 12;
            document.getElementByID("heisei-year").textContent = heiseiYear;
            document.getElementByID("year").textContent = fullYear;
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
　<br />
    <div id="heisei">
        今年は平成<span id="heisei-year"></span>年です
    </div>
    <div id="ad">A.D.<span id="year"></span></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

質問のコードには誤字がいくつかあり、特にイベント名が誤っているため処理が実行されていません。

- DOMCintentLoaded → DOMC**o**ntentLoaded
- Stri**o**ng → String
- getElementByID → getElementByI**d**

なお最初の問題は発生しないイベントに登録している状態のためエラーとはなりませんが、残りの2個はイベントが実行されればブラウザの「開発者ツール」にエラー箇所が出力されますのでご確認ください。

Comment: ご指摘の部分を修正することで解消されました。
初歩的な質問に丁寧にご対応頂き、ありがとうございます。